# Has the killer monopolised the serial actions?

Tags: word-choice

*Serial* is an adjective so often associated with the word *killer* that its  usage in a different context may sound sinister.
Can *serial* be used properly to describe other activities such as:

- a serial entrepreneur
- a serial piano player

  or alternatively what would be a more appropriate adjective to describe activities carried out in regular succession?

Comment: What on earth would a serial piano player be? Somebody who doesn't play two pianos at once?

Comment: Serial ports???

Comment: Serial monogamist is often heard

Comment: There's also *serial monogamy,* which has a slight negative connotation (implication of a lack or fear of commitment). But *serial* is widely used in jargon neutrally, as in a *serial circuit* or a *newspaper serial.*

Comment: @BraddSzonye We think alike. Don't think it's so negative though - better than being a serial adulterer.

Comment: Midsomer Murders is a typical killer serial.

Comment: @Mynamite Yeah, it's only a slight connotation, and I think it's just because most people don't really approve of serial monogamy. Not sure whether the term was inspired by *serial killer.*

Comment: And let's not forget _serial commaists_.

Comment: A USB port is not sinister.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not like there are fixed rules, but serial is most often used to describe things that it's unusual to do a lot, usually things that are unusual to do even once, like serial killer or serial adulterer. A serial entrepreneur makes sense in that context; it describes a person who is constantly starting new ventures. A serial piano player doesn't really make sense to me, because if you are competent at an instrument then by definition you practice it a lot.

edit: to answer the second part of your question, how about "prolific"?

Comment: +1 for prolific -- this is the word most often used to describe an author who writes several books in quick succession, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A new phrase is popping up now about attitudes towards relationships: *serial monogamist".

> "Luckily or unluckily, I don't have a ton of exes," he says. "Before my wife, I was in only two relationships – one for five years and another for three-and-a-half years. I'm a [serial monogamist](http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20789498,00.html)." - Ty Burrell in People magazine

There is even an entry in Wikipedia:

> "One theory is that this pattern pacifies the elite men and equalizes reproductive success. This is called the Male Compromise Theory. Such [serial monogamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogamy#Serial_monogamy) may effectively resemble polygyny in its reproductive consequences because some men are able to utilize more than one woman’s reproductive lifespan through repeated marriages."